# Overloading operator [] for N-dimensional structure

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I made an N-dimensional structure with vectors and templates:

```
//----------------N-dimensional vector--------------------------------
template<int dim,typename T> class n_dim_vector {

public:
    typedef std::vector<typename n_dim_vector<dim - 1, T>::vector> vector;
};

template<typename T> class n_dim_vector <0, T> {

public:
    typedef T vector;
};
```

It can be instatiaated with different dimnsion-counts and is prt of a class that represent a search space.

```
template<int dim, typename T> class n_dim_ssc {

private:
    typename n_dim_vector<dim, T>::vector searchspace;

};
```

My problem: I cannot get `operator[]` right to access `searchspace` properly, specifically the return type.

I tried:

```
template<typename V> std::vector<V>& operator[](unsigned i) {
    return searchspace[i];
}

T& operator[](unsigned i) {
    return searchspace[i];
}
```

at first, thinking the compiler would derive  `typename V` as whatever type `searchspace`  contained at all but the last level. Thats what `T& operator[](unsigned i)` was for.

But alas, doen't work this way. And I  cannot work out how it would

**EDIT** Don't fear, I do not access empty memory, the structure is initialized and filled, I just didn't include the  code for clarity's  sake.

Also, I don't intend to access it with a single integer, I wanted to use `searchspace[i][j]..[k]`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but that's a *terrible* way to lay out data in memory. You end up with gazillions dynamic allocations and indirections. It's usually much better to have one, contiguous space of memory and address it in multidimensional strides.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You have several stacked vectors, and you want to access it via a single `int` parameter. Wouldn't it be better to implement `operator()(size_t ... I)` which returns a `T::value_type`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I just couldn't ccome up with any better structure where I dont know the sizes in advance. Feel free to recommend something better, I'd appreciate it

Comment: @TeaOverflow: The idea is to allocate memory once to hold `N1*N2* ... * Ndim` values, and then access your entry `[i1][i2] ... [idim]` via the index `i1+N1*(i2+N2*(... + idim) )`. For example, in 2D, instead of using `std::vector<std::vector<double> >(N1,std::vector<double>(N2))` you would use `std::vector<double>(N1*N2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to let compiler deduces the return type is `auto`:

In C++14:

```
auto operator[](unsigned i) { return searchspace[i]; }
```

In C++11:

```
auto operator[](unsigned i) -> decltype(searchspace[i]) { return searchspace[i]; }
```

Comment: Impressively simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering to your comment

> Feel free to recommend something better, I'd appreciate it.

The following code shows one way to handle the multidimensional vector at once, i.e. non-recursively. It could be improved in several ways which I didn't consider for now (for instance, I wouldn't want to use and pass that many arrays but rather use variadic parameter lists. This however requires much more and more diffcult code, so I'll let it be.)

```
#include <numeric>

template<size_t Dim, typename T>
struct MultiDimVector
{
    std::array<size_t, Dim> Ndim;
    std::array<size_t, Dim> stride;
    std::vector<T> container;

    MultiDimVector(std::array<size_t, Dim> const& _Ndim) : Ndim(_Ndim), container(size())
    {
        stride[0] = 1;
        for (size_t i = 1; i<Dim; ++i)
        {
            stride[i] = stride[i - 1] * Ndim[i - 1];
        }
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return std::accumulate(Ndim.begin(), Ndim.end(), 1, std::multiplies<size_t>());
    }

    size_t get_index(std::array<size_t, Dim> const& indices) const
    {
        //here one could also use some STL algorithm ...
        size_t ret = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i<Dim; ++i)
        {
            ret += stride[i] * indices[i];
        }
        return ret;
    }

    T const& operator()(std::array<size_t, Dim> const& indices) const
    {
        return container[get_index(indices)];
    }
};
```

You can use it like

```
MultiDimVector<3, double> v({ 3, 2, 5 });   //initialize vector of dimension 3x2x5
auto a = v({0,1,0});                        //get element 0,1,0
```

But as I wrote, the curly brackets suck, so I'd rewrite the whole thing using variadic templates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you're not initializing any memory inside the vector and just trying to return non-existent memory spots. Something on the line of the following (*WARNING: uncleaned and unrefactored code ahead*):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int dim,typename T> class n_dim_vector {

public:
    typedef std::vector<typename n_dim_vector<dim - 1, T>::vector> vector;
};

template<typename T> class n_dim_vector <0, T> {

public:
    typedef T vector;
};

template<int dim, typename T> class n_dim_ssc {

public:
    typename n_dim_vector<dim, T>::vector searchspace;

    n_dim_ssc() {}
    n_dim_ssc(typename n_dim_vector<dim, T>::vector space) : searchspace(space) {}

    n_dim_ssc<dim-1, T> operator[](std::size_t i) {

        if(searchspace.size() < ++i)
            searchspace.resize(i);
        return n_dim_ssc<dim-1, T>(searchspace[--i]);
    }

    typename n_dim_vector<dim, T>::vector get() {
        return searchspace;
    }

};

template<typename T> class n_dim_ssc<0,T> {

public:
    typename n_dim_vector<0, T>::vector searchspace;

    n_dim_ssc() {}
    n_dim_ssc(typename n_dim_vector<0, T>::vector space) : searchspace(space) {}

    typename n_dim_vector<0, T>::vector get() {
        return searchspace;
    }
};



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  n_dim_ssc<0, int> ea;
  int a = ea.get();

  n_dim_ssc<1, int> ea2;
  auto dd2 = ea2[0].get();

  n_dim_ssc<2, int> ea3;
  auto dd3 = ea3[0][0].get();
}
```

<kbd>[Try it out](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7025ec0d06f600f)</kbd>

will work with an accessor method (you can modify this as you want).

Anyway **I strongly have to agree with Kerrek**: a contiguous memory space accessed in a multi-dimensional array fashion will both prove to be faster and definitely more maintainable/easier to use and read.